# Setting two divs to display inline, yet they're showing up diagonally

Tags: html, css

I have two divs inside of a navbar, and when attempting to display them inline, they show up like this rather than side by side:

[image]

Here's the HTML:

```
<!--Nav starts here-->
    <nav class="navbar">

        <div class="navbar-item-set">
            <div class="navbar-item">
                <a href="index.html" class="navbar-text">
                    <img src="images/sad_robot.png" alt="" width="45" height="45"/>
                    <br>    
                    ID2 Games
                </a> 
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-item">
                <a href="index.html" class="navbar-text">
                    <img src="images/sad_robot.png" alt="" width="45" height="45"/>
                    <br>
                    Fizz + Hummer
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </nav>
<!--Nav ends here-->
```

And the respective CSS:

```
.navbar{
    height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    background-color: black;
}

.navbar-item-set{
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.navbar-item{
    display: inline;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 150px;
    color: white;
}
```

What's causing this strange layout?

Comment: display inline-block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
.navbar-item{
display: inline;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 150px;
color: white;
}
```

To

```
.navbar-item{
display: inline-block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 150px;
color: white;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `<br/>` elements in the HTML should do the trick.